# How to call events when using the "Logout" facebook button?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I have a login button in the Sample HelloFacebookActivity from facebook.

After I login successfully, then the button switch to the status "Logout"

When I click on "Logout" facebook button, it logged out correctly. I want to add an event when the user clicks the "logout" button to handle some my logic code... What should I do?

Thank you.

Edit: I use the SDK for Android Native

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following to logout the session

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
session.closeAndClearTokenInformation()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Can I use the following code:

Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        session.addCallback(new StatusCallback() {
   
   @Override
   public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if(state == SessionState.CLOSED) {
     //do my codes
    }
   }
  });

Comment: @thanhvinh Yes you can. For more details check http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/Session

Answer (score 0):

You can make your custom Logout Button and write your code ,

write , `[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];`

and write this line for Logout from fb.

Comment: I use Facebook SDK for Android native, if I can use that code?

Answer (score 0):

The best option would probably be to use the Javascript sdk and subscribe to the `auth.logout` event. Here's an example:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
  alert('You logged out');
});
```

Here are the docs on [subscribing to events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/).. Let me know if this all makes sense :)

Comment: Is there any way to use the native for Facebook Android Native SDK ?